# jquery mobile, error with select menu in Android with Chrome version 50

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome, select, mobile

I have updated  my Chrome browser to last version and I have the following problem:

When I select an option of a select menu it does not appear selected, I repeat the process of the selection and then it is selected OK. If I try to select other option it happens the same, first time bad, second time OK. It is happening since I have update to version 50 of Chrome, with previous version 49 it worked OK.

I am using a Huawei Y5 with Android 5.1.1, it happens the same with a Nexus with Android 6.

The version of jquery mobile that I have is 1.4.5

It seems only happens with Chrome version 50 in Android, in desktop works fine. In the browser that Huawei has, works OK.

To test this problem is easy, just go to the demo of select menu of jquery mobile:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu/

One important thing, in previous versions of jquery mobile works fine, examples:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/selects/

Is there any way to resolve this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Félix.

Answer (score 3):

I have to question the logic behind JQuery Mobile hiding the toolbars on **select** element focus by default.  The native browser **select** elements overlay the page in their various special ways, and even the non-native select popup (which you get when specify the data attribute **data-native-menu="false"** in html or **nativeMenu: false** in the selectmenu options) is absolutely positioned as a dialog.  This means that the toolbars really do not intrude on the real-estate given to the selectmenu options as they'll always overlay everything including the toolbars.  To me, this makes the code from line 12664 - 12692 commented as: *this hides the toolbars on a keyboard pop to give more screen room* rather unnecessary for select elements.

**Workaround/solution**: thankfully jQuery-Mobile does nicely allow you to override this setting in your header/footer with the data-attribute data-hide-during-focus - simply set this to:

**data-hide-during-focus="input, textarea"**

and it won't try to hide the toolbars anymore when a select element gets focus.

i.e. simply change your header from this:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
  Header
</div><!-- /header -->
```

to:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false"  data-hide-during-focus="input, textarea">
  Header
</div><!-- /header -->
```

... and the same goes for the footer.

Comment: Hi Clint, First of all thank you very much for yout answers. I have tried both of them and the first one works fine in portrait, but in landscape does not work. The secon solution works in both orientations, but I've found one issue: if I enter data in an input text, close the keyboard and try to select an option of a combo, the issue happens. I instead of close the keyboard, I tap the screen and after that I select one option, then it works fine. I think that the focus out of the input and the focus in of the select do not synchronize very well in that case.

Comment: Hi @faabalia

Interesting observation regarding the text input - don't worry, there's a solution to this which just expands on my previous answer. By adding data-hide-during-focus="input, textarea" jquery-mobile will still attempt to hide the header/footer for input and textarea fields. As you've observed, this still causes issues for your selectmenu field because it attempts to show the header and footer again when the input text field loses focus. You can entirely remove the hide header/footer on focus functionality by instead adding

    data-hide-during-focus=""

to your header and footer

Comment: Hi Clint, I have tested your suggestion but if I put input, data-hide-during-focus="" it does not work , I have the same issue as If do not put it. I think that it attempts to show the header and footer again for all the elements (select, input, textarea, ...).

Comment: Debugging with Chrome in line 12670 of jquery mobile file the value of o.hideDuringFocus has the value: "input, textarea, select".

Comment: Hi @faabalia - it sounds to me like you've put data-hide-during-focus="" on the wrong element.  This goes on the header and footer, not the input element as you've written in your comment above.  If you want to confirm that this is the correct way to fix things, you can first change hideDuringFocus: "input, textarea, select", to hideDuringFocus: "" on line 12442 of the jquery.mobile script file (v1.4.5).  Once you've confirmed that this resolves your issue roll this back and use the method I've described above to fix this in a nicer way.

Comment: Hi Clint, I have tested what you suggested me and it works OK, except two case: if I am in an input field entering data and after that I just close the keyboard and then go to a select menu and display the options, the flash happens again and it does not work. The second situation that does not work is when I am in the input entering data with the keyboard shown, if I go directly to a select menu, the flash happens and when I try to select an option it is not selected. Really I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Hi @faabalia - I reproduced the issue you described last week when I added data-hide-during-focus="input, textarea" on the header and footer.  When I added data-hide-during-focus="" instead on the header and footer the issue went away.  Can you confirm that you're setting data-hide-during-focus to a blank string in every header and footer?

Comment: Hi Clint, I confirm you that I have in the header: <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-alt-icon ui-header ui-bar-a" data-hide-during-focus="" role="banner">  and in the footer: <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-alt-icon ui-header ui-bar-a" data-hide-during-focus="" role="banner"> , I have also tried with data-hide-during-focus=" ", and it happens the same issue.

Comment: Hi @faabalia, according to the code snippet you added above, your header and footer both have the same data-role="header"...  I assume you meant for one of these to be ="footer".  Either way, I would suggest you try to simplify the header and footer entirely first as just <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-hide-during-focus="">Header</div> and <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-hide-during-focus="">Footer</div> to see if the issue still occurs.

Comment: Hi Clint, I put as you said: <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-hide-during-focus=""> and <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-hide-during-focus=""> , the issue mantains :-(

Comment: Hi Clint, It seems that is an issue of Chrome, see this link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/-JLlY3eKQ-E , I have tested in Chrome beta version (51), and the flash happens but the option is selected. No changes in code have been necessary. I suppose that they have to correct the flash effect.

Comment: Hi Clint, I have also installed de Android WebvView System beta version (51.0.2704.36) and in the App also works OK. If you want to test, you can find the apk in: http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-system-webview/

Comment: @Clint Thanks, this took care of it while the bug lasts, you got my upvote! :)